# OpenGL SL intilisation any vector in openGLSL fragment shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-fragments, glsl

My fragment shader starts like this:

```c
void main() {
    vec3 incrementalGaussian;
    incrementalGaussian.x = 1.0f / (sqrt(2.0f * pi) * sigma);
    incrementalGaussian.xy *= incrementalGaussian.yz; 
}
```

I have doubt that if we defined `vec3 incrementalGaussian;` is it valid to use                `incrementalGaussian.x` this?

If yes, `incrementalGaussian.xy` means?

Comment: I mean to say that, is "incrementalGaussian.x" is equvilant to "incrementalGaussian[0]" ??
If yes, what will be "incrementalGaussian.xy" means??

Comment: Use [swizzling](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vectors) for component and sub-vector access. e.g., `vec2 v = incrementalGaussian.xy;`

Comment: Yes, `[0]` is one way to access a single component in a vector. If you want to read/write multiple components, swizzling is how this is done. `incrementalGaussian.xy` can be thought of as a statement like `vec2 (incrementalGaussian [0], incrementalGaussian [1])`. Likewise, `incrementalGaussian.yz` is basically `vec2 (incrementalGaussian [1], incrementalGaussian [2])`. There are ways to change which component xyzw references, but for simplicity let us avoid this.

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions. Sry for replying so late.